# how to add PID inside cgroup.procs with non-root privileges in cgroup-v2 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, non-root-user, cgroups

I created cgroup in `/sys/fs/cgroup`. I called it `testGrp` and I need this `cgroup` to be controlled by non-root user so I changed the ownership of the whole cgroup directory

```shellsession
/sys/fs/cgroup$ sudo chown -R normUser testGrp/
```

I made sure that all files inside `testGrp` are owned by the new user `normUser`, actually this user can change the conrollers files like updating `io.max` normally but it is permitted to add any PID inside the `cgroup.procs`.

```shellsession
/sys/fs/cgroup/testGrp$ ll cgroup.procs 
-rw-r--r-- 1 normUser root 0 Aug 21 14:13 cgroup.procs
/sys/fs/cgroup/testGrp$ whoami
normUser 
/sys/fs/cgroup/testGrp$ echo $$ > cgroup.procs 
bash: echo: write error: Permission denied
```

I thought that changing the ownership of the cgroup would solve the issue of the root privileges but actually it didn't help.

So how could I control the cgroup without using the root user?

Answer (score 0):

The rule used by the kernel is that in order to migrate a process from cgroup A to cgroup B, you must first have permissions to migrate it to the cgroup that is the **common ancestor** of both A and B.

If you use systemd and your initial cgroup is under `/user.slice/user-xxxx.slice/`, then the closest common ancestor between that and your `/testGrp` is just `/`, which you indeed do not have permissions for.

In fact, if your distribution uses systemd, then I would really recommend using systemd's built-in cgroup hierarchy management, i.e. creating .slice units to define hierarchy and then moving processes into .scope units via `systemd-run [--user]`.

Comment: I need to add a running processes to this cgroup

Comment: Hence the suggestion to use .scope units – unlike .services, they're meant to be used with a preexisting process ID. Either way, though, you might not be able to get away from the privilege requirement.